# ¿Como obtener la información de un Componte QTreeWidget cuando este es seleccionado?

Tags: c++, qt

Buenas, 
Estoy trabajando con la librería QT y se me ha presentado lo siguiente.

Estoy generando un esquema en forma de árbol de proyectos, con el componente `QTreeWidget`, como se muestra a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es poder retornar el nombre del proyecto o el indice que ocupa en el árbol un determinado proyecto, cuando este sea seleccionado.

En la documentación de QT el metodo que lo realiza es el siguiente:

> QList QTreeWidget :: selectedItems () const
>
> Devuelve una lista de todos los elementos no-oculto seleccionados.

Como podría obtener alguno de los datos mediante la utilización de este método? ya que me parece el apropiado para esta situación. Seria ideal ver algún ejemplo.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si revisamos la documentación de [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#currentItem) (versión 5.X de Qt) vemos lo siguiente:

> QTreeWidgetItem *QTreeWidget::currentItem() const
>
> Returns the current item in the tree widget.

Es decir, si solo vas a permitir un elemento seleccionado por vez este método te devuelve un puntero al elemento de la fila seleccionada.

Para obtener el valor, según la documentación de [QTreeWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#text), nos bastaría con usar la siguiente función:

> QString QTreeWidgetItem::text(int column) const
>
> Returns the text in the specified column.

Para tu caso particular quedaría así:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* fila = MiQTreeWidget->currentItem();
QString texto = fila->text(0);
```

Comment: estuve mirando el ejemplo y me ha servido. Ahora bien, como se ve en la imagen que agrego al post en cada proyecto se desprende un subárbol. Por ejemplo en el proyecto **Prueba** se desprende alumnos, docentes, entre otras. El tema esta que al seleccionar por ejemplo docentes `texto` sera igual a docentes. Como puedo filtrar esto, tendiendo en cuenta que solo necesito que la variable `texto` contenga la raiz de los proyecto generado, es decir para el caso de la imagen, `Texto ` solamente sea igual a (asd,test, prueba). Saludos.

Comment: @marcosvasquez cada nodo conoce a su padre... nada te impide navegar hacia arriba en la jerarquía para tener certeza sobre el nodo seleccionado... si eso se complica mucho quizás deberías cambiar `QTreeWidget` por `QTreeView` e implementar un modelo de datos `QAbstractItemModel` para mapear a tu modo los datos...

Comment: ok, esta bien. En ese caso, que pasos debería  seguir  o que debería realizar para obtener la raiz del nodo seleccionado?

Comment: @marcosvasquez Los nodos tienen un [método parent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#parent)